# Google Apps Script Timing Out - Appending 7 sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that hits the Google Script time out limit - it is appending together 7 sheets each containing around 300-500 rows, however it times out each time. Is there any way I can optimise the script to prevent it failing?

```
function concatAllSheets()
{
  var includedSheet=['GA_DE','GA_SE','GA_FR', 'GA_IT', 'GA_ES', 'GA_UK', 'GA_NL'];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("#ID HERE#");
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  var sheetName='Data'
  var mother=ss.insertSheet(sheetName);
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
  {
    var sht=allSheets[i];
    if(includedSheet.indexOf(sht.getName())>-1)
    {
      var rng=sht.getDataRange();
      var rngA=rng.getValues();
      for(var j=0;j<rngA.length;j++)
      {
        var row=rngA[j];
        mother.appendRow(row);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need the atomic guarantee provided by `appendRow`? If not use `getRange`, `getLastRow` and `setValues`... They will be incomprehensibly faster.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you would append each sheet row by row when you could append the entire contents of each sheet in 1 call using setValues()

```
  var motherNextRow = 1; // start at row 1

  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
  {
      var sht=allSheets[i];
      if(includedSheet.indexOf(sht.getName())>-1)
      {
         var rng=sht.getDataRange();
         var rngA=rng.getValues();

         if(rngA.length>0){
            mother.getRange(motherNextRow, 1, rngA.length, rngA[0].length).setValues(rngA);
            motherNextRow += rngA.length;
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: (I'm also assuming there's a reason why you're consolidating the values of the 7 sheets using Apps Script.  Google Sheets is great for maintaining live connections between multiple sheets using formulas)

Comment: `appendRow` is useful for cases requiring atomic operations. For a volatile / high-traffic sheet, the last row can change between acquisition and value-setting - i.e. data can be overwritten. Hence why I asked for clarification, and requested OP to try to solve this themselves ;)